# What does a "perfect step" mean in One More Dash?

Tags: one-more-dash

The mobile game *One More Dash* has various challenges including "dash # perfect steps in sequence".
But what does it mean by "perfect step"?

Comment: I've created a tag for this game. This is right, right?

Comment: It's right. Right

Answer (score 2):

A perfect sequence is dashing from circle to circle without hitting any walls the number of times needed to meet the challenge. So 'Dash 35 Perfect Steps In Sequence' means, dash to 35 circles, in a row, without hitting any walls or, of course, exploding.